# Non linear spring mass IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, perturbation-theory

I’ve read a solution to a question in the Applied Mathematics book , but it seems incorrect to me . So here is the question :

Non-dimensionalize and find the leading order solution to the IVP:
$ m y’’ + a y’ + ky^3 = 0$ where $y(0)=0, my’(0)=I$ where $ m \ll 1$ and all other constants are $O(1)$
So they rescale as $t_c = t/(a/k)$ and $y_c = y/(I/a)$, the scale $a/k$ does not make it dimensionless so it seems incorrect to me ?
I took $t_c = t/T$ where $T =  a^3/(kI^2)= O(1)$ ( and $t_c$ is dimensionless, as you can check as $a$ is $MT^-1$ and $k$ is $ML^{-2}T^{-2}$ and $ I $ is $MLT^{-1}$).
With this choice I rescale and find :

$ \epsilon y_c’’ + y_c’ + y_c^3 = 0$
with $ \epsilon = m/(aT) \ll 1 $

Note: $T$ was chosen so that the coefficient in front of $y_c^3$ is $1$
So for the outer solution you get to solve $ y_o’ + y_o^3=0$ which gives $ y_o = (C+2t_c)^{-1/2}$ 
For the inner part we set $t_2 = t_c/\epsilon$ and $Y(t_2)=y_c(t_c)$ to get $ Y’’ + Y’ + \epsilon Y^3 = 0$

Which gives $Y(t_2) = 1-e^{-t_2}$ with the initial condition $Y(0)=0, Y’(0) = 1 $ 
The matching gives $ Y(\infty)=1=y_o(0)=C^{-1/2}$

So I get the composite solution as :
$ y(t) = I/a\left((1+2ta\epsilon/m)^{-1/2}-e^{-at/m}\right)$

(where I used $ \epsilon=m/(aT)$ to simplify)

Here is the book solution :
[image]

Note : in some Lecture where you have $y$ instead of $y^3$ the solution appears to be $ y(t) = I/a \left( e^{-t/(a/k)}-e^{-(t/(a/k)/\epsilon}\right)$ where they scale here indeed with $T=a/k, \epsilon=mk/a^2$, which seems to be the solution provided here as $ u(\tau)=u(t/(a/k))=y(t)/(I/a)$

Comment: Also in their solution, there is a weird $Y'$ (typo ?) and they forgot the $u^3$ to me ... so their solution is not correct in any case (?)

Comment: The outer solution results from $y'+y^3=0$. // And yes, your observations appear to be correct, it gives the impression that several, perhaps at least 3, people have edited this example without having understood the whole of it.

Comment: Thank you @LutzLehmann, you mean edited the solution of the book ? Most of solutions have big typos in it yes :/

Comment: Yes. There is the original equation of the Duffing class, the strangely linear equation, some hint that perhaps a multi-scale approach was tried and not completely removed. This looks more like the first author wrote down the example, then some assistant started to write down the solution and stopped half-ways, then some third attempted to complete it but had some transcription errors,... a full-on conspiracy theory.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And funny consipary :-)